# how to upgrade openssl for apache 2.2.29 - still using old 0.9.8 version

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, openssl

I am running a 10.04LTE server where I do want to upgrade openssl for apache.

Therefore I downloaded openssl 1.0.2c and apache 2.2.29 and compiled both. The server is starting, but is using the old ssl version:

```
curl --head http://localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2015 06:00:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8k
Last-Modified: Sun, 18 Mar 2012 19:56:07 GMT
```

However, Openssl is installed in new version:

```
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2c 12 Jun 2015
```

While the original version stayes in place:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
```

I compiled apache with:

```
./configure --with-included-apr --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-so     
--enable-rewrite --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --enable-ssl=shared
--enable-deflate --enable-expires --enable-headers
```

Apache did not start before I included:

```
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
```

According to the mod ssl website this is only available for apache 1.x

Not sure what is going wrong here. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your Apache installation is unable to link the shared libraries of your new OpenSSL installation. Run the command  `ldd /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_ssl.so` (with the apporpriate path to your mod_ssl.so). You'll see that mod_ssl.so is not linking to the libraries in `/usr/local/ssl/lib`

You have a couple options to fix the problem:

**Option #1 - Link in the libraries:**

Open `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf` for editing and add the following line: `/usr/local/openssl/lib`

Re-compile Apache (remember to `make clean`) and it should work.

If that doesn't work. You could also try specifying `LDFLAGS` directly with your `configure` command:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/ssl/lib \ ./configure --with-included-apr --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-so     
--enable-rewrite --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --enable-ssl=shared
--enable-deflate --enable-expires --enable-headers
```

**Option #2 - Upgrade the system OpenSSL:**

Re-install OpenSSL with the config line `./config --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared`

When the prefix is not specified in your config line, the OpenSSL installer will default to `/usr/local/ssl`.

Quick install instructions:

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2-latest.tar.gz
tar -zxf openssl-1.0.2*
cd openssl-1.0.2*
./config --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared
make
make test
make install
```

Comment: I dont undertand why openssl should be installed in /usr The library is now correctly installed in /usr/local/ssl but apache is using some old version despite configuring --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl

Comment: Thank you! The command ldd helped to solve the problem. I have included the old mod_ssl in the apache httpd.conf. The right one is the following: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so which is now using the new ssl library

Comment: Ahh interesting, I'm glad you got it solved!

Answer (score -1):

Download the 1.0.2k zip file from this site.
https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/
Extract the files.
Stop the Apache service.
Make a backup of these 3 files in C:\xampp\apache\bin
ssleay32.dll
libeay32.dll
openssl.exe
Copy the same 3 files from the extract files location to C:\xampp\apache\bin
Start the Apache service.

Comment: Question is about linux (Ubuntu), not Windows, for which the DLLs you mention are for.