# Updated the openssl version, but the old version still appears as being used

Tags: ssh, ssl, openssl

I updated to openssl 1.0.2h, but when I hit

```
lsof | grep -i libssl
```

I still get 1.0.1e

```
nginx     19645        nginx  mem       REG         182,420273    441256     398853 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
```

I tried restarting nginx, apache and mysql, but the old version still remains although openssl version returns

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

I followed the tutorial from [here](https://syslint.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-openssl-on-centos-7-or-rhel-7/).

Also, before I posted this, I followed the answer from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/701086/how-to-upgrade-openssl-for-apache-2-2-29-still-using-old-0-9-8-version).

Do you know how I can make it use the latest version?

Comment: Did you restart `nginx`?

Comment: Yep. Unfortunately, it didn't do the trick. Not only nginx uses the old version of ssl, but also apache, mysql, postfix, root etc.

Comment: In additon to @garethTheRed's question, how did you install openssl and nginx? What OS is this?

Comment: @EEAA it's a CentOS 6

Comment: Not sure for CentOS 6, but an openssl update in Ubuntu _requires_ a system reboot as well

Comment: @Colt I did a reboot -h now, but still the same result on lsof | grep -i libssl

Comment: Can you answer @EEAA's question about how you installed it?

Comment: @garethTheRed I followed the tutorial from [here](https://syslint.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-openssl-on-centos-7-or-rhel-7/)

Comment: That means you have two versions - the official `yum` installed version and the version you compiled.  The next question is: Why do you feel you need to upgrade?

Comment: @garethTheRed Because there's [a security issue](https://blog.cloudflare.com/yet-another-padding-oracle-in-openssl-cbc-ciphersuites/) with 1.0.1e. Version 1.0.2h solves this.

Comment: What does `rpm -q --changelog openssl | grep 2016-2107` show? If version 1.0.1e came from RedHat/CentOS then it should be patched.

Comment: @garethTheRed [It shows nothing](http://i.imgur.com/oNDAUed.png), actually. :| Version 1.0.1e was installed by me as well a while back.

Comment: Maybe you should consider reverting to using `rpm` for your package and install 1.0.1e from the repo?  That should be patched.

Comment: nginx is often statically compiled against openssl, so unless you know it's linked, then you'll also need to rebuild or reinstall nginx itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are solving this problem the wrong way.  You need to understand [Red Hat's patching policy](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting/?sc_cid=3093) (CentOS following upstream as it does, this is therefore CentOS's patching policy as well).

As long as C6 is supported (ie, [until 2020-11-30](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product?highlight=%28lifetime%29)), and as long as you keep your C6 box fully up-to-patch, you will be running non-vulnerable versions of OpenSSL **even though the OpenSSL version number does not change**.

Once you start building your own version of OpenSSL, you will find you have to rebuild (or at least relink) lots of major tools, to get them to pick up your handbuilt version, and you will have to do this each time a new version of OpenSSL comes out.  It is a slough of despond, it is completely pointless, and it is unprofessional to boot.

Answer (score 0):

You may run `ldd /path/to/nginx` to see how it's linked.